# Akka: communicating and handling special state (non-error) between actors

Tags: java, akka, actor

I am brand new to Akka (Java lib, v2.3.9) and am trying to understand actor dependency and fallback/fault tolerance.

Say I have two actors, `StormTrooper` and `DarthVader`:

```
// Groovy pseudo-code
class StatusReport {
    private final Report report

    StatusReport(Input report) {
        super()
        this.report = deepClone(report)
    }

    Input getReport() {
        deepClone(this.report)
    }
}

class StormTrooper extends UntypedActor {
    ActorRef lordVader  // Injected with reference to DarthVader

    @Override
    void onReceive(Object message) {
        if(message instanceof PerformReport) {
            PerformReport pr = message as PerformReport
            Report report = ReportUtils.generateReport(pr.config)
            StatusReport statusReportMsg = new StatusReport(report)
            lordVader.tell(statusReportMessage, ...)
        }
    }
}

class DarthVader extends UntypedActor {
    @Override
    void onReceive(Object message) {
        if(message instanceof StatusReport) {
            // Do something meaningful with the status report.
        }
    }
}
```

Under some circumstances, `DarthVader` is essentially NULL and should be a no-op. That is: when `StormTrooper` decides to send a `StatusReport` message to `DarthVader`, he:

1. Might have been configured to be alive and functional, in which case `DarthVader` will correctly respond to the status report; or
2. The user may have taken action (via configuration) such that `DarthVader` must be **intentionally** offline/unresponsive/no-op

In the latter case when `DarthVader` is *supposed* (I emphasize this to distinguish this from a use case when `DarthVader` is supposed to be alive/functioning but is in a faulty/error state) to be no-op, I'm not sure how to communicate that back to `StormTrooper`, who must simply call `fizzBuzz#derp()` if `DarthVader` is no-op.

#### Solution #1: State-based no-op detection

```
class StormTrooper extends UntypedActor {
    ActorRef lordVader  // Injected with reference to DarthVader

    @Override
    void onReceive(Object message) {
        if(message instanceof PerformReport) {
            if(lordVader.isNoOp) {
                fizzBuzz.derp()
            } else {
                PerformReport pr = message as PerformReport
                Report report = ReportUtils.generateReport(pr.config)
                StatusReport statusReportMsg = new StatusReport(report)
                lordVader.tell(statusReportMessage, ...)
            }
        }
    }
}

class DarthVader extends UntypedActor {
    boolean isNoOpMode = false

    @Override
    void onReceive(Object message) {
        if(message instanceof StatusReport) {
            if(!isNoOpMode) {
                // Do something meaningful with the status report.
            }

            // Obviosuly, if we are in no-op mode, do nothing.
        }
    }
}
```

My uncertainty here is that ALL instances of `DarthVader` actors/threads must be in the same state (no-op mode being on/off applies universally to all of them), and so I'm not sure if this solution is even viable of in keeping with Akka best practices.

#### Solution #2: Throw specialized exception

```
class StormTrooper extends UntypedActor {
    ActorRef lordVader  // Injected with reference to DarthVader

    @Override
    void onReceive(Object message) {
        if(message instanceof PerformReport) {
            try {
                PerformReport pr = message as PerformReport
                Report report = ReportUtils.generateReport(pr.config)
                StatusReport statusReportMsg = new StatusReport(report)
                lordVader.tell(statusReportMessage, ...)
            } catch(DarthVaderNoOpException dvnoExc) {
                fizzBuzz.derp()
            }
        }
    }
}

class DarthVader extends UntypedActor {
    boolean isNoOpMode = false

    @Override
    void onReceive(Object message) {
        if(message instanceof StatusReport) {
            if(!isNoOpMode) {
                // Do something meaningful with the status report.
            } else {
                throw new DarthVaderNoOpException()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But using exceptions to control flow is a general no-no, and may even trigger built-in Akka supervisor behavior (reacting to exceptions may cause Akka to restart `StormTrooper`, etc.).

#### Solution #3: Send a response message back

```
class StormTrooper extends UntypedActor {
    ActorRef lordVader  // Injected with reference to DarthVader

    @Override
    void onReceive(Object message) {
        if(message instanceof PerformReport) {
            PerformReport pr = message as PerformReport
            Report report = ReportUtils.generateReport(pr.config)
            StatusReport statusReportMsg = new StatusReport(report)
            lordVader.tell(statusReportMessage, ...)
        } else if(message instanceof DarthVaderNoOp) {
            fizzbuzz.derp()
        }
    }
}

class DarthVader extends UntypedActor {
    ActorRef stormTrooper
    boolean isNoOpMode = false

    @Override
    void onReceive(Object message) {
        if(message instanceof StatusReport) {
            if(!isNoOpMode) {
                // Do something meaningful with the status report.
            } else {
                DarthVaderNoOp noOpMsg = new DarthVaderNoOp()
                stormTrooper.tell(noOpMsg, ...)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this seems like a cumbersome, chatty solution.

So I ask: what's the best way for `DarthVader` to indicate to `StormTrooper` that it's in no-op mode, such that `StormTrooper` knows to call `fizzBuzz.derp()`? Remember that if `DarthVader` is in no-op mode, all instances/actors/threads of `DarthVader` are in no-op mode, not just one particular instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is few possible solutions. First, you want to read if `DarthVader` is in `NoOp` mode from config then actor is created (Typesafe Config will work fine).

```
Config vader = conf.getConfig("vader");
bool isNoOpMode = vader.getBoolean("state");
```

So you can set it universaly for the application.

For `DarthVader` himself, as you said, you can do chatty solution (respond to `StormTrooper`), or utilize your first approach with conjuction with `Ask` pattern. You will send report to `DarthVader` and will return Future which will await for `DarthVader` response.

```
Timeout timeout = new Timeout(Duration.create(5, "seconds"));
Future<Object> future = Patterns.ask(lordVader, statusReportMsg, timeout);
```

Please note, you do not want to call `Await` method, but to handle response inside `onComplete`, for example:

```
final ExecutionContext ec = system.dispatcher();

future.onComplete(new OnComplete<VaderResponse>() {
  public void onComplete(Throwable failure, VaderResponse result) {
    if (failure != null) {
      // Derp
    } else {
      // Report acknowledged
    }
  }
}, ec);
```